# AngularFire 2 Getting Data from Firebase Without authkey

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2

I am trying to create some kind of messages feed. Because I display all messages on feed I don't need authid of message

This is how I store data:
[image]

```
this.msgData =this.db.list(`/messages/`).valueChanges();
    this.msgData.subscribe(msg =>{

console.log(msg);


    });
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you see because of authid there are 2 groups so its 2 dimensional array

What I'm trying to do is for example access avatar by msg[0].avatar --- this returns 1st messages avatar.i guess i need a custom function for msg or can angularfire do it for us ??

thanks